# M2DOC how to customize Table

Tags: m2doc

I implemented my owned service that returm MTable to insert a table in my doc.

Someone have examples on how to merge cells ?
I would like, for example, a table with 2 columns. The first column composed of only one cell, and the second column composed of 3 cells.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the moment this is not supported by M2Doc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
rowCell.setVMerge(MTable.MCell.Merge.CONTINUE)
```

Or:

```
rowCell.setVMerge(MTable.MCell.Merge.RESTART)
```

To merge cells vertically.